# Winnower Font Size

Tags: fonts, size

I am curious about changing the font size in the "Winnower" setting. [12pt], [11pt] codes are not working. Any help?

```
\documentclass**[12pt]**{winnower}
\lhead[]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: "Winnower," sounds like a name from *Lord of the Rings*... where can we find this ominously-named document class?

Comment: https://thewinnower.com/formatting_guidelines

Comment: Is there anywhere in the formatting guidelines where it specifies you can perform this change? If this is for publication submission, I'd suggest avoiding that, since it would probably be overridden anyway.

Comment: the whole point of a publisher class is to remove choice from the author and force the publication style, so it is quite expected that such a class does not have options for font size.

Answer (score 3):

The `winnower.cls` available from from https://thewinnower.com/formatting_guidelines does not contain any option handling code at all. Since it loads `article.cls` under the hood, it would be easy to add

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

to the class file. This way all options would be forwarded to `article.cls`. You might provide this as a suggestion to the class author.